# Multiprocessing in Python with multiple (keyword) arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to save 2 json files at same time in multiprocessing.
For this first I need to serialize array. When I assign `cls=NumpyArrayEncode` class in `args` in multiprocessing then I'm getting error because we can't assign `cls=NumpyArrayEncode` probably due to equal `=` sign in `args` in multiprocessing.

Below is my code only for one process. For second process idea is same.

```
# json serialization
class NumpyArrayEncode(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, np.ndarray):
            returno.tolist()
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)

json_data = np.array([[3, 5, 6], [8, 12, 6]]) # example

with open('test.json', 'w') as fn:
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = json.dump, args=(json_data, fn, cls=NumpyArrayEncode)) # here is problem that we can't add equal `=` sign in `args` in multiprocessing.
```

How to add `cls=NumpyArrayEncode` as arguments in multiprocessing?

Looking for kind suggestion

Comment: Actually not. I already read mentioned thread but it was different from my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options: Use the `kwargs` parameter (see the [`multiprocessing.Process` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) to pass keyword arguments:

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=json.dump,
                        args=(json_data, fn),
                        kwargs={"cls": NumpyArrayEncoder})
```

or you use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=functools.partial(json.dump, cls=NumpyArrayEncoder),
                        args=(json_data, fn))
```